# Reactjs App cannot build due to some dependency issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

After I delete `node_modules` and reinstall everything of my reactjs project, I can still run `yarn start` no problem, but when `yarn build`:

```
yarn run v1.22.4
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ craco build
craco:  *** Cannot find ESLint loader (eslint-loader). ***
Creating an optimized production build...
(node:54555) [DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_NORMAL_MODULE_LOADER_HOOK] DeprecationWarning: Compilation.hooks.normalModuleLoader was moved to NormalModule.getCompilationHooks(compilation).loader
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/example_app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

TypeError: dependency.getCondition is not a function
    at ModuleGraph.setResolvedModule (/Users/example_app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/ModuleGraph.js:196:15)
    at /Users/example_app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1850:20
    at /Users/example_app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:352:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/example_app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/example_app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at AsyncQueue._handleResult (/Users/example_app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:322:21)
    at /Users/example_app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:305:11
    at /Users/example_app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1303:4
    at /Users/example_app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:85:6
    at /Users/example_app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:39:11
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I am not sure what happened. Can't really figure out how to resolve this by reading the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and upgrading webpack v5.75.0 is solved it.